# jQuery How to disable buttons defined within an Array of Buttons

Tags: jquery, button

Thanks to all for the previous help messages. Well I am kind of working on this code and I'm stuck at this one point, not sure how to get through this. Hope you can help.

Here's the problem, I have a dialog box which opens with some text fields in it and at the end there are 2 buttons **OK** and **Cancel**, what I want to do is, check a boolean value for permissions, if in case its false, disable to **OK** button, here is how buttons are defined,

```
dialogBox.dialog ({
    modal:true,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    buttons: {
        OK : function () {
            // Some code here
            },
        Cancel : function () {
            // Some code here
            }
    }
    // Some more code below but irrelevant to problem
});
```

Now, I need to disable the OK button using jQuery, how can I do it, please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could set the buttons as an array (which allows setting disabled attribute. And then re-setting the buttons array every time the boolean is changed (if you can monitor it somehow).

```
dialogBox.dialog ({
modal:true,
width: 600,
height: 600,
buttons: [
{
    text: "Ok",
    disabled: "false",
    click: function() { // Some code here }
},
{
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function() { // Some code here }
}    
]
// Some more code below but irrelevant to problem
});
```

Then when boolean value is changed to false do:

```
$( "#dialogBox" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", [
{
    text: "Ok",
    disabled: "true",
    click: function() { // Some code here }
},
{
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function() { // Some code here }
}    
]
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog buttons created by jQuery UI are located in a `<div>` element that exposes the `ui-dialog-buttonpane` class.

Since your `OK` button is the first one in the set, you can use the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to match it:

```
dialogBox.dialog("widget")
         .find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first")
         .prop("disabled", true);
```